# Why is a paraboloid surface formed with a rotated liquid?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, centrifugal-force, fluid-statics

I've read in Wikipedia that:

> "if a liquid is contained in a cylindrical vessel and is rotating around a vertical axis coinciding with the axis of the cylinder, the free surface will assume a parabolic surface of revolution known as a paraboloid. The free surface at each point is at a right angle to the force acting at it, which is the resultant of the force of gravity and the centrifugal force from the motion of each point in a circle."

Why does it form a paraboloid? My particular difficulty is that all points are supposed to be acted upon same forces so I don't understand the reason they are rotating at circles having different distances from the axis of rotation.

Comment: What research effort have you made as an attempt to understand this phenomenon? What particular difficulty in this research have you encountered to prompt a specific question?

Comment: @safesphere I have edited my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fluid in a rotating cylinder](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88340/)