# Fluid rotating in theta direction in a tank

Tags: fluid-dynamics

> A Newtonian fluid of constant density $\rho$ is in a vertical cylinder of radius R with the cylinder
> rotating about its axis at angular velocity $\omega$. Find the shape of the free surface at steady state.Consider the cylindrical coordinate system for analysis. Consider the pressure (P) to be a function of two coordinate system r and z. Refer to the figure below for more details.
>
> [image]

I used Navier Stoke's equation in the angular direction since the principal motion is in ${\theta}$ direction.

$$\begin{aligned}
&\theta \text { -component: }\\
&\rho\left(\frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial t}+u_{r} \frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial r}+\frac{u_{\theta}}{r} \frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial \theta}+\frac{u_{r} u_{\theta}}{r}+u_{z} \frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial z}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial P}{\partial \theta}+\rho g_{\theta}+\mu\left[\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial r}\right)-\frac{u_{\theta}}{r^{2}}+\frac{1}{r^{2}} \frac{\partial^{2} u_{\theta}}{\partial \theta^{2}}+\frac{2}{r^{2}} \frac{\partial u_{r}}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial^{2} u_{\theta}}{\partial z^{2}}\right]
\end{aligned}$$

Reducing it with assumptions I get

\begin{aligned}
0=\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial r}\right)-\frac{u_{\theta}}{r^{2}}
\end{aligned}

\begin{aligned}
c=\left(r \frac{\partial u_{\theta}}{\partial r}\right)-\int\frac{u_{\theta}}{r} dr
\end{aligned}

Now it's clear that in order to solve it I have to integrate it twice, i.e., consider $u_{\theta}$ not a function of $r$. But physics bites me from inside. Can someone provide me a logic to this?
Another thing is why $u_{\theta} = r \omega$ i.e., ( $sin (\theta) = 1 $) not valid here?

Comment: Is $ u_{\theta}$ the theta component of velocity?

Comment: yes, http://ingforum.haninge.kth.se/armin/FLUID/EXER/NAVIER_STOKES_EQ.pdf

Comment: I have a feeling that your diagram is inaccurate because usually it looks like a parabola cavity  once it starts rotating

Comment: I am not dismissing your problem but am suggesting  edits for clarity's sake

Comment: Talking about the diagram, well how will you know that the profile is parabolic without actually performing the expt?(I know how to prove it parabolic).

Comment: I just need to know why $u_{\theta}$ is not $r \omega$.

Comment: I realised that I have made wrong assumptions possibly; $u_{\theta}$ would depend on z.

Comment: thanks for the edits @Buraian

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Navier-Stokes is taking a steamroller to crack a nut.

Your fluid is roting as a solid body so $v_\theta =r\omega$.  You can find the shape of the surface by observing that in the fluid is stationary in the rotating frame, and in that frame  the potential energy is
$$
V(r,z)=\rho g z- \frac 12 \rho \omega^2 r^2, 
$$
a sum of the gravitational and centrifugal potentials.
The surface must be an equipotential, so
$$
z(r)=  \frac 1{2g} \omega^2 r^2,
$$
which is a parabola of revolution.

Your original problem askes you to use the pressure. Euler (divided by $\rho$) tells us that
$$
\frac{\partial {\bf v}}{\partial t}+ \left({\bf v}\cdot \nabla \right) {\bf v}= - \frac 1 \rho \nabla P- {\bf g}
$$
Now  ${\bf v}=(-\omega y, \omega x, 0)$ so $$
 \left({\bf v}\cdot \nabla \right) {\bf v}= -\frac 12 \omega^2 \nabla (x^2+y^2)
$$
so
$$
\nabla\left(\frac  P\rho - \frac 12\omega^2  r^2 +gz\right)=0.
$$
Thus again $P$ is constant on
$$
z= \frac 1{2g}\omega^2 r^2.
$$

Comment: thanks for the answer but if you see it's a homework problem. I have to follow the instructions. On the other hand in the description, I have written about why $v_{\theta}  = r \omega$ is wrong. I know how to do it by Newton's ways. Also an answer which I do not require is here too https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88340/fluid-in-a-rotating-cylinder

Comment: If $v$ were not $\rho \omega$ you are not rotating a s rigid body. Viscosity will  come into play until it is rotating rigidly.

Comment: that means that I have reduced the equation incorrectly. Thanks. Please also add this too your answer

Comment: I would not have answered in so detailed a manner if I known it was an hw problem. But anyway: what is the "$\sin \theta$ tha ask about?

Comment: oh sorry, I actually pasted an image initially of the assignment but then, I read write latex and in hurry forgot to put that header.

Comment: $sin (\theta)$ is fine. No problem's with that. I just wanted to confirm $v_{theta} = r \omega$

Comment: There is Coriolis in the rotating frame, but the fluid is not moving in that frame so there is only centrifugal.  I wrote Euler in an *inertial lab frame*, so neither Coriolis nor centrigulal --- just Euler's equation with its convective derivative.  It's  the same physics, but differently descrubed in different frames.