# Fluid in a Rotating Cube

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, superfluidity

Fluid in a rotating cylinder has a paraboloid shape. But, I was wondering what shape would the liquid take in a rotating cube. If possible, explain mathematically.

Comment: According to https://www.bc.edu/content/dam/bc1/schools/mcas/physics/Herczynski/AJP-88-475.pdf, the shape of fluid will be paraboloid in any vessel.

Comment: The shape that the liquid takes is always parabolic

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/88340/fluid-in-a-rotating-cylinder