# Rotating fluid shape with its own gravity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, fluid-statics, rotational-kinematics

Hi almost every student knows the rotating bucket with a fluid problem as described here:

[Fluid in a rotating cylinder](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88340/)

I wanted to do the same for a rotating fluid in free fall (like in the ISS) to show that it will take the shape of a sphere.

Then we also consider by a symmetry of the final result that we can guess the analysis along the axis $Oz$ of the final shape. In this case, the velocity components will be $$v_x=-\omega y, v_y=\omega x, v_z=0.$$ Taking Euler's equation:

$$\frac{\partial \vec{v}}{\partial t}+(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla) \vec{v}=-\frac{1}{\rho} \operatorname{grad} p+\vec g.$$

Considering that $\partial \vec{v} / \partial t=0$, the projections on the three axis on Euler's equation are (we take into account the radial self-gravity of the fluid with the Shell theorem $g(r)=g_0(r/R)$):

$\begin{aligned} & x \omega^2=-\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial p}{\partial x}+g_0 \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{R} \\ & y \omega^2=-\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial p}{\partial y}+g_0 \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{R} \\ & 0=-\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial p}{\partial z}+g_0 \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{R}\end{aligned}$

If I integrate that stuff as we do for the rotating cylindrical bucket i don't fall back at the end on the equation of a spherical shape. For example see how ugly is the integration of the first line:

$\dfrac{1}{2}x^2\omega=-\dfrac{p}{\rho}+\frac{1}{2} x \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}+\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right) y^2+\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right) z^2$

I can't see any possible way that the final result to give the equation of a sphere?

Any idea?

PS: I will try tomorrow in spherical coordinates to see if it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It won't be a sphere, but instead an [MacLaurin spheroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin_spheroid) or more gerally a  [Jacobi  ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_ellipsoid)

Comment: Interesting… thanks!

Comment: I made some searches these last 2 days. Even in the book of MacLaurin itself i wasn't able to found the detail proof. Maybe you know a good source where i can found it?

Comment: I have never done the full math myself--- only the small angular velocity case, which can be solved using the Legendre polynomials. The book by Chandrasekar is suppose to be the standard refrenece, but he is always hard to read.

Comment: Ok i will try to look for the small angular velocity case that is the one that is interesting for me. Thanks for your help and don't hesitate to comment if you have a good source for that special case!

Comment: The slow rotation is a homeowrk set from my class last fall: https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys508/fa2023/508hw10.pdf  Problem 3.